# jquery accordion - onclick opening all accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a custom jquery accordion and I am stuck with the code, when I click on accordion title, its opening both of the accordion where it should open the one where I have clicked, following are the codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".acc-wrap > .acc-head").on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).siblings('.acc-body').slideUp(200);
            $(".acc-wrap > .acc-head").attr('class', 'acc-head opened');
        } else {
            $(".acc-wrap > .acc-head").attr('class', 'acc-head closed');
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('.acc-body').slideUp(200);
            $(this).siblings('.acc-body').slideDown(200);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.projects-list {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.acc-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #264796;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  position: relative;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.opened {
  position: relative;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.opened:after {
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.closed {
  position: relative;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.closed:after {
  content: "\f056";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
.acc-body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="projects-list">
  <div class="acc-wrap">
    <div class="acc-head opened"> Vestibulum </div>
    <div class="acc-body"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. </div>
    <div class="acc-head"> Vestibulum  2</div>
    <div class="acc-body"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use the next-function instead of the siblings-function:

[https://api.jquery.com/next/](https://api.jquery.com/next/%60)

```html
<style>
    .projects-list {
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #E0E0E0;
      padding: 15px 0;
      font-family: Roboto;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .acc-wrap {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .acc-wrap > .acc-head {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      background-color: #264796;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 600;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      transition: all 0.2s linear;
      position: relative;
    }
    .acc-wrap > .acc-head.opened {
      position: relative;
    }
    .acc-wrap > .acc-head.opened:after {
      content: "\f055";
      font-family: fontAwesome;
      position: absolute;
      right: 15px;
    }
    .acc-wrap > .acc-head.closed {
      position: relative;
    }
    .acc-wrap > .acc-head.closed:after {
      content: "\f056";
      font-family: fontAwesome;
      position: absolute;
      right: 15px;
    }
    .acc-body {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      display: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```

`

Comment: thanks for the answer, changing from sinblings-fucntion to next-function worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
$(this)
  // Add/ Remove active and opened as both will always be together.
  .toggleClass('active opened')
  // Add closed if active not present else remove it
  .toggleClass('closed', !$this.hasClass('active'))
  // Go to next element
  .next()
  // Toggle slide on every click
  .slideToggle(200)
```

Also note that `$(".acc-wrap > .acc-head");` is pointing to all accordion headers. You should always try to use `this` and navigate to necessary div.

#### Sample

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".acc-wrap > .acc-head").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this
      .toggleClass('active opened')
      .toggleClass('closed', !$this.hasClass('active'))
      .next()
      .slideToggle(200)
  });
});
```

```css
.projects-list {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.acc-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #264796;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  position: relative;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.opened {
  position: relative;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.opened:after {
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.closed {
  position: relative;
}
.acc-wrap > .acc-head.closed:after {
  content: "\f056";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
.acc-body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="projects-list">
  <div class="acc-wrap">
    <div class="acc-head">Vestibulum</div>
    <div class="acc-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</div>
    <div class="acc-head">Vestibulum 2</div>
    <div class="acc-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this method is good as well but I decided to go with @MartinWunderlich answer using next-function.

Comment: That is a good answer and even I have upvoted it. Just take reference from my answer on how to use different functions to avoid `if..else` and reduce conditions

Comment: yes, thats already taken in regards to functions. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add This it is much easy and fast than yours http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h

Comment: Note, answers with just reference link are considered as bad answers and might get downvote/ deleted

Answer (score 0):

`$(".acc-wrap > .acc-head:not(.opened)");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using referencing the elements by class you want to use "this".find("element").attr() etc etc. You are targeting all elements matching the class .acc-head when using this $(".acc-wrap > .acc-head");

Alternatively you could reference the targeted element using $(".acc-wrap > .acc-head.active");

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="max-width: 300px;">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#264796;color:#ffffff">
        <h4 class="panel-title" id="ab">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6dec" >Vestibulum
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="plus"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span id="minus"  style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6dec" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body" style="">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="panel-title" style="font-size: 18px;"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. </a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:-20px">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#264796;color:#ffffff">
        <h4 class="panel-title" id="ab1">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#lorem2" >Vestibulum 2  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span id="plus1"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span id="minus1"  style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="lorem2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="panel-title" style="font-size: 18px;"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. </a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var counter = -1;
         $("#ab").click(function(){
             counter++;
            if (counter % 2 === 0) {
                 $("#plus").css('display','none');
                 $("#minus").css('display','inline');
            }
           else{
                $("#plus").css('display','inline');
                $("#minus").css('display','none');
            }

        });
          $("#ab1").click(function(){
             counter++;
            if (counter % 2 === 0) {
                 $("#plus1").css('display','none');
                 $("#minus1").css('display','inline');
            }
           else{
                $("#plus1").css('display','inline');
                $("#minus1").css('display','none');
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: So if I have 10 accordion I will have 10 click functions??

Comment: No,if you make the id as a class then u should write only one click.

Comment: Okay, but its completely different code, I want to use my code which has already been answered below!